# Unable to iterate through list - Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am unable to iterate through rows of data (that I saved into a list).

Below is the sample code

```
Timelist = []
for row_cells in sheetname.iter_rows(min_col=1,max_col=6,min_row=2):
             Timelist = row_cells[1].value

for x in Timelist:
    print(x)
```

I want to get iterate through row values for that column (in this case column 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to append the values to your list `Timelist` inside the for loop instead of assigning, to be able to iterate over it later for printing `x`

```
Timelist = []

for row_cells in sheetname.iter_rows(min_col=1,max_col=6,min_row=2):
    Timelist.append(row_cells[1].value) # <--- append here

for x in Timelist:
    print(x)
```